# Problemas con arreglos en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo este código en el que primero aun arreglo le asignas el tamaño (estoy utilizando letras en lugares de números) y en "teoría" después te permite agregar los caracteres hasta que al final imprime la posición y el carácter que se agrego (en orden normal y después invertido).

El problema está en que a la hora de querer ir agregando los caracteres solo te permite agregar en las posiciones nones del arreglo.

Me ayudaría mucho si me dieran la explicación detallada del porque está mal…

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

main() {

    char  arreglo[MAX];
    int i,NUM;

    printf("\nIngresar cantidad de elementos a ingresar => ");
    scanf("%d",&NUM);
    printf("Ingresar %d elementos al arreglo :\n",NUM);

    for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
       printf("v[%d] => ",i);
       scanf("%c",&arreglo[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEl arreglo original es : \n");
      for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
      printf("v[%d] => %c\n",i,arreglo[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEl arreglo invertido es : \n");
    for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
      printf("v[%d] => %c\n",i,arreglo[(NUM-1)-i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta, cada vez que hagas scanf, un flush del buffer, ya que por lo que dices que solo coge las posiciones nones, probablemente las pares esté metiendo un salto de linea al darle al intro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu lees caracter a caracter, el salto de línea que añades entre dos caracteres no se descarta automáticamente, sino que se lee en las posiciones *pares* del array.

Puedes forzar a `scanf` para que descarte este separador:

```
scanf(" %c",&arreglo[i]);
//     ^ Este espacio descarta los espacios y saltos de linea que haya antes
//       del caracter a leer
```

O bien puedes, como te han indicado vía comentarios, usar `fflush`:

```
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c", &arreglo[i]);
```

La pega de esta solución es que `fflush` solo está pensado **para streams de salida**, es decir, `stdout`. Usarlo con `stdin` puede que te funcione y puede que no (depende de la benevolencia del compilador)... así que si te da por usar este mecanismo es bajo tu responsabilidad.

Por otro lado, conviene recordar que según el estándar, la función `main` **debe** devolver un entero, es preferible ceñirse la estándar para evitar sorpresas desagradables al cambiar de compilador:

```
int main(void) {
```

Comment: Use la solucion de dejar un espacio dentro del **scanf**, pero no me quedo muy claro porque toma en cuenta los saltos de linea si dentro del **printf("v[%d] => ",i);** no escribí ninguno.

Comment: @Dummyboy no toma saltos de linea en el `scanf`. Los saltos de linea que ves son resultado del eco que se realiza de la entrada (tu introduces un enter y eso provoca un salto de línea quieras o no). No obstante, si tu problema es otro, por favor, edita la pregunta para dar más información y algún ejemplo de la salida

Comment: Con la primera solución que propusiste fue suficiente, solo que no me quedaba claro lo de los saltos de linea pero con la explicación que me acabas de dar me quedo muy claro ¡gracias!